# JavaFx ListView event before changed

Tags: listview, events, javafx, onchange

I'm working with my JavaFX 8 application, want to add a pop-up window and confirm if user want to exit the page without saving, the window is supposed to jump when user selecting another item in the listview, which means changing focus to another listview item.

first, I use a change Listener to handle the selectedIndexChange event, just like below

```
listView_a.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>(){
        @Override 
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldV, Number newV){                

            if(newV != null){
                int selectedIdx = newV.intValue();

                if (0 == selectedIdx) {                 
                    reloadForOverview();
                } else if (1 == selectedIdx) {
                    reloadForA();
                } else if (2 == selectedIdx) {
                    reloadForB();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to find some event handler activated before the "changed" event happen, and stop the "change" happen, index changing and so on. Trying "MouseClicked event" but end with fail, now i'm using invalidation event to achieve this, but in vain, like this

```
listView_A.getFocusModel().focusedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
        {   
            if (oldValue != null && oldValue.intValue() >= 0)
            {
                if (resetFocus())
                {
                    listView_A.getFocusModel().focus(oldValue.intValue());
                }       
            }       
        }
    });
```

It still goes to "Changed" and i just can't stop it, please tell me how to stop the "Changed" event and prevent listView_A from changing it's index if I don't want it to.

I'm new here, if there is anything I didn't notice, just let me know, thanks a lot!